# Memory leak with Interaction Triggers in MVVM Light Toolkit Silverlight

Tags: memory-leaks, mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

[Visual Studio 2012 Project with memory leak](https://mega.co.nz/#!V08FUAZT!VutIR3LWXBqsjMN2CgxceV2dIq8YTVxczepQVVfFZo0)

Hello!
I've found a memory leak when using Interaction Triggers in the MVVM Light Toolkit.
I use this xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MemoryLeakTest.MainPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
         mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
         xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
            xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.SL5"
         x:Name="control"
         DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LeakObjects}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border  Width="300" BorderThickness="6" BorderBrush="BlueViolet" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Grid Background="{Binding ColorBrush}" >
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=DataContext.Command}"  Width="100" Height="40" Content="Tryck!">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                        <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=DataContext.Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </Button>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

and then i rebind the list LeakObjects so that it creates new items.
The old items (xaml) like buttons and text blocks are still in memory and doesn't GC.

If I write

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=DataContext.Command}"  Width="100" Height="40" Content="Press!"/>
```

and use the buttons Command parameter there is no memory leak but if I use the

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
          <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=DataContext.Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
 </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

there is a major leak.

The problem is that there are no Command parameters on grids etc.

The project in the link has this very simple project demonstrating the problem.

Is there a way to circumvent the memory leak? Maybe I'm using it wrong.

It is crucial that I find a way to fix this because this memory leak is all over our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this leak as well. I've solved it by not using the EventToCommands and rather using just plain event handlers and calling the commands from these methods in page code-behind. It's not that clean, but it works and the page is Garbage Collected as expected.
Or you could use **InvokeCommandAction** instead, works for me.
http://www.dotnetpatterns.net/entries/21-Memory-Leak-issue-with-EventToCommand-passing-binding-to-RelayCommand